# Why does Test::LeakTrace say this Perl code is leaking memory?

Tags: perl, memory-leaks

`Test::LeakTrace` says code leaking. I don't understand.

I do not understand output of `Test::LeakTrace`, and it is too long for this post. Some leaks from Test system, but others? No.

This is the code.

```pl
use 5.26.0;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use Test::LeakTrace;

sub spawn {
    my %methods = @_;
    state $spawned = 1;
    my $object  = bless {}, "Spawned::Class$spawned";
    $spawned++;
    while ( my ( $method, $value ) = each %methods ) {
        no strict 'refs';
        *{ join '::', ref($object), $method } = sub { $value };
    }
    return $object;
}

no_leaks_ok {
    my $spawn = spawn( this => 2 );
    is( $spawn->this, 2 );
}
'no leaks';

done_testing;
```

I get weird things like this:

```txt
# leaked SCALAR(0x7f9b41a069c0) from leak.pl line 11.
#   10:        $spawned++;
#   11:        while ( my ( $method, $value ) = each %methods ) {
#   12:            no strict 'refs';
# SV = IV(0x7f9b41a069b0) at 0x7f9b41a069c0
#   REFCNT = 1
#   FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
#   IV = 2
```

And this:

```txt
# leaked GLOB(0x7f9b411b22a0) from leak.pl line 9.
#    8:        state $spawned = 1;
#    9:        my $object  = bless {}, "Spawned::Class$spawned";
#   10:        $spawned++;
# SV = PVGV(0x7f9b41a29530) at 0x7f9b411b22a0
#   REFCNT = 1
#   FLAGS = (MULTI)
#   NAME = "Class4::"
#   NAMELEN = 8
#   GvSTASH = 0x7f9b4081a0a8    "Spawned"
#   FLAGS = 0x2
#   GP = 0x7f9b40534720
#     SV = 0x0
#     REFCNT = 1
#     IO = 0x0
#     FORM = 0x0
#     AV = 0x0
#     HV = 0x7f9b41a24730
#     CV = 0x0
#     CVGEN = 0x0
#     GPFLAGS = 0x0 ()
#     LINE = 9
#     FILE = "leak.pl"
#     EGV = 0x7f9b411b22a0  "Class4::"
```

Nothing makes sense to me. Reference counts are 1.

Comment: I don't know anything about Test::LeakTrace, but at a rough guess it seems to be complaining about the subs you're adding to the symbol tables at run-time, which of course won't be freed. In particular, it's comlaining about the typeglob you add with the *{...} = . I don't know enough details of that module to say whether such reports are false positives.

Comment: See also [Why is Devel::LeakTrace leaking memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57005774/2173773) and [How can I completely delete a package in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3807061/2173773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code leaks. They are intentional leaks, but leaks nonetheless.

You create a package that is never freed.<sup>[1]</sup> In it you create a glob that is never freed. To this glob you assign a sub that is never freed. The sub captures a variable, so it's never freed.

The module is doing its job and telling you about this.

---

I encountered a few surprises confirming the above was what was happening. The rest of this answer identifies them and explains them.

I'll be using this program (`a.pl`):

```perl
use 5.010;
use Test::More tests => 1;
use Test::LeakTrace;

sub f {
   state $spawned = 1;
   my $object  = bless {}, "Spawned::Class$spawned" if $ARGV[0] & 1;
   $spawned++                                       if $ARGV[0] & 2;
   delete $Spawned::{"Class".($spawned-1)."::"}     if $ARGV[0] & 4;
}
```

---

If we do `$spawned++;` but not the bless:

```
$ perl a.pl 1
1..1
ok 1 - leaks 0 <= 0
```

Expected.

---

If we do the bless but not `$spawned++;`:

```
$ perl a.pl 2
1..1
ok 1 - leaks 0 <= 0
```

huh!? We created global symbols. Shouldn't those be considered leaks? So why did the OP produce leaks, then? I'll come back to this.

---

If we do both:

```
$ perl a.pl 3
1..1
not ok 1 - leaks 8 <= 0
#   Failed test 'leaks 8 <= 0'
#   at a.pl line 11.
#     '8'
#         <=
#     '0'
#
# [snip]
```

huh?! Why is it suddenly mentioning the global symbols we created?! I mean, it's what we expect, but we expected it above too. I'll come back to this.

---

Finally, we'll also undo the changes we made.

```
$ perl a.pl 7
1..1
ok 1 - leaks 0 <= 0
```

As expected, if we release the additions we made to the global symbol table, it no longer reports any leaks.

---

Now let's address the questions I raised.

Imagine if you had done something like

```perl
state $cache = { };
```

You wouldn't want that hash to be reported as a leak even though it's never freed. To that end, Test::LeakTrace evaluates the test block twice, ignoring leaks from the first call.

> *Leaked SVs* are SVs which are not released after the end of the scope they have been created. These SVs include global variables and internal caches. For example, if you call a method in a tracing block, perl might prepare a cache for the method. Thus, to trace true leaks, `no_leaks_ok()` and `leaks_cmp_ok()` executes a block more than once.

That's why `perl a.pl 2` didn't result in any reported leaks.

But `perl a.pl 3` and the OP's code (intentionally) leak every time they are called, not just the first. Test::LeakTrace has no way to know those leaks are intentional, so you get what I suppose you could call false positives.

---

1. When I say "never freed", I mean "never freed until global destruction". Everything gets freed then.